# load images in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports-2010

please describe How to add picture at run time in the crystal report using C#

```
private void LoadImage(DataRow objDataRow, 
                              string strImageField, string FilePath) 
{
   FileStream fs = new FileStream(FilePath, 
                          System.IO.FileMode.Open,  System.IO.FileAccess.Read); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `crystalrepoert.setdatasource(datatable)` to load pictures in crystal report file, the image column of datatable apeears in report.

also you can you use runtime dataset like this:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/saj/CrystalReports03192006090510AM/CrystalReports.aspx