# Crystal Report load image (bytes[]) at runtime with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I have a report where there is a static image, but I need to load the image dynamically.

Already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706662/add-image-to-crystal-report-at-runtime), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/128239/dynamically-change-an-image-in-a-crystal-report-at-runtime), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582805/load-a-byte-into-an-image-at-runtime) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105366/load-images-in-crystal-reports)

All I tried without success. I need some sample code.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load images dynamically I created a new class/model called *ImageModel*.

```
public class ImageModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }     
    public Byte[] ImageBytes { get; set; }
}
```

This class has a field called *Image*, it will load the image.
The next step is add *ImageBytes* field to the report.
Through Crystal Report interface, using the Field Explorer, it was to create a new connection. In this new connection I used my *ImageModel* class as a model.
By adding the *ImageBytes* field, I noticed that Crystal Reports added a type *crBlobFieldObject* object.
To load the image was necessary to make the following code:

```
public Byte[] GetImageBytes(string image_name)
{
    Byte[] bytes = null;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(image_name))
    {
        string app_path = ((System.Web.HttpRequestWrapper)this.Request)
                                .PhysicalApplicationPath;
        app_path += "Content\\images\\";
        string full_path = app_path + image_name;
        //
        if (System.IO.File.Exists(full_path))
        {
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(full_path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            bytes = br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(br.BaseStream.Length));
        }
    }
    return bytes;
}
```

The main code looks like this:

```
public JsonResult GenerateCrystalReportImage()
{
    List<ImageModel> list_image = new List<ImageModel>();
    //
    ImageModel imageone = new ImageModel();
    imageone.Id = 1;
    imageone.Name = "Image name one";
    imageone.Description = "This is a image description one";
    imageone.Image = GetImageBytes("imageone.png");
    list_image.Add(imageone);
    //
    ImageModel imagetwo = new ImageModel();
    imagetwo.Id = 2;
    imagetwo.Name = "Image name two";
    imagetwo.Description = "This is a image description two";
    imagetwo.Image = GetImageBytes("imagetwo.png");
    list_image.Add(imagetwo);
    //
    ReportDocument rp = new ReportDocument();
    rp.Load(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Reports/") + "Test.rpt");
    rp.SetDataSource(list_image);
    rp.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat, 
                            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response, 
                            false, 
                            "image_list_" + DateTime.Now);
    rp.Close();
    return Json(new
    {
        data = "ok",
        results = 1,
        success = true,
        errors = String.Empty
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```